# What is an alternative way to say "I am done"?

Tags: word-choice

Is there a different way to say "I am done" to mean that I completed a task? I am trying to avoid misunderstandings with somebody who doesn't speak English.

Comment: I always thought that "I'm done" means smth like "I'm totally exhausted"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*I have finished* or *I am finished*

Answer (score 4):

If you wish to put the emphasis on the task, you could try "the task is finished" or "the task is completed."